# Java 8 filter for contains

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java 8 and when I am trying to put a filter for all those cities which contains one letter. It doesn't work for me. However, when I run it with old approach it works.

```
    List<String> cityList = new ArrayList<>();
    cityList.add("Noida");
    cityList.add("Gurgaon");
    cityList.add("Denver");
    cityList.add("London");
    cityList.add("Utah");
    cityList.add("New Delhi");

    System.out.println(cityList);

/* Prior to Java 8 Approach */      
    for (String city : cityList) {
            if(city.contains("a")){
                System.out.println(city + " contains letter a");
            }
        }
/* Java 8 Approach */           
    System.out.println(Stream.of(cityList).filter(str -> str.contains("a")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Here is the output

```
Noida contains letter a
Gurgaon contains letter a
Utah contains letter a
[]
```

Can you please explain me where am I am making mistakes.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You just made a `Stream<List<String>>` and not a `Stream<String>`...

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use `cityList.stream()` rather than `Stream.of(cityList)`. Reason being that currently, `Stream.of(cityList)` returns a `Stream<List<String>>` whereas you want `Stream<String>`. You can still accomplish your task by using your current approach but you'll need to flatten the `Stream<List<String>>` into `Stream<String>` (I do not recommend as it causes un-necessary overhead hence it's better to use `cityList.stream()`).

That said, here is how you should go about accomplishing your task:

```
System.out.println(cityList.stream().filter(str -> str.contains("a")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 2):

`Stream.of(cityList)` creates a `Stream<List<String>>` having a single element - your input `List`.

You need to use `cityList.stream()` in order to get a `Stream<String>` contaning the elements of your input `List`.

```
System.out.println(cityList.stream().filter(str -> str.contains("a")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

outputs

```
[Noida, Gurgaon, Utah]
```

The only reason you code passed compilation is that both `List` and `String` have a `contains` method that returns a `boolean`.

Comment: I was reading through the [Java 8 Lambdas] (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030713.do) and there was an example given like this `List<String> beginningWithNumbers
= Stream.of("a", "1abc", "abc1").filter(value -> isDigit(value.charAt(0)))
.collect(toList());
assertEquals(asList("1abc"), beginningWithNumbers); `  So, I got confused with this. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Ashish The example in your comment uses a different variant of Stream.of(), which takes multiple items as arguments and constructs a Stream of those items. In your question, however, you called a variant that takes a single argument (which happened to be a List) and creates a Stream of a single element.